# How to terminate psql process inside Jenkins job with SIGINT instead of SIGTERM when aborted?

Tags: jenkins, psql

I have a Jenkins job that fires a long-running SQL function in a PostgreSQL database using a `psql` command in a shell (bash) script. Sometimes the computation needs to be terminated to unblock other queries on the server. But if the job is manually aborted, the SQL function stays running (within a `postgresql` process) on the server although the `psql` command gets terminated.

I found out that `psql` needs to be aborted by SIGINT to cancel the query properly, but Jenkins apparently sends SIGTERM to all processes spawned in within the job execution.

I tried trapping the TERM signal in the job script and sending SIGINT to the `psql` that was run on background, but `psql` still received SIGTERM first and finished without stopping the query.

According to [this](https://gist.github.com/datagrok/dfe9604cb907523f4a2f) Jenkins kills the whole process group of the script, but starting `psql` in a separate process group (`set -m`) also doesn't help.

Is there any way to stop the `psql` query gracefully upon Jenkins job abort?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this workaround. Add trap SIGTERM signal for the psql process and kill the running process with normal SIGTERM in the cleanup procedure:

```
function clean() {
    echo "Interrupted: psql #$1" >&2
    kill -SIGINT $1
    wait $1
    echo "psql ended" >&2
}

psql -c 'select pg_sleep(10)' &
pid=$!

trap "clean $pid" SIGTERM
```

Then run the script through SSH Publisher build step (Publish Over SSH Plugin). Two checkboxes must be set for the job to work correctly:

1. Exec in pty in Transfers block -> Advanced button
2. Fail the build if an error occurs in Server block -> Advanced button